# Apache2: AH01630 Client denied by server configuration after rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-16.04, lamp

I get this error, when trying to access a url which gets rewritten internally and I don't know why or how to fix it:

```
[Sun Apr 01 10:XX:XX.042734 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 20813] [client 84.XX.XX.90:16450] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /dev/home.php
```

Basically, I am trying to rewrite all html requests, so when you e.g. try to access /dev/file.html, it's rewriting it to dev/file.php

I am able to access /dev/file.php without issues, but when I try to access /dev/file.html (which should point to the .php file) I am getting a 403 Forbidden error.

I have tried several things, I found here on Stackoverflow, as well as in various blogs, but nothing helped.
My current vhost conf looks like this:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com # My actual files contain the correct domain and not "example"

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    #Include /var/www/html/.htaccess
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    <Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
     </Directory>
     <Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       #AllowOverride None
       Require all granted # since 2.4
     </Directory>
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    # Redirects
    Include /etc/apache2/redirects.conf # Doing all redirects/ rewrites here
</VirtualHost>
```

My redirects.conf file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 302 "/index.html" "http://example.com/maintenance.html"
Redirect 302 "/index" "http://example.com/maintenance.html"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.html$ $1.php
```

I am hosting the website using a virtual instance on google cloud, Ubuntu 16.04 and my Apache version is 2.4.18.

I would greatly appreciate any hint! I am normally used to Node serving, so the conf stuff in apache is quite unusual to me.

Thanks!

Comment: does .htaccess work with any rules ?

Comment: where is / **dev** /home.php?

Comment: I am not using any .htaccess files due to performance. Also, /dev/home.php is the relative URL path after example.com/. It is physically located in /var/www/html/dev/home.php

Comment: @Kyrill ok, do the above rules work fine ? is there any rule before these ?